# ComboBox2 items populate when ComboBox1 has value

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF. I have a LINQ query which populates `ComboBox1`. The value selected from `ComboBox1` should then be used in the where clause of a LINQ query which I want to populate `ComboBox2`.

Is there an event trigger so that when a value has been selected in `ComboBox1`, `ComboBox2` will populate with LINQ query results? I've written the LINQ query, but not too sure how to make it run on the event.

This is what I want to run after `ComboBox1` value has been selected

```
private void ComboBox2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string comboName = ComboBox1.Text;
    int recipId = RecipID(comboName);
    ComboBox2.ItemsSource = MainWindow.qryGiftList(recipId);
    ComboBox2.DisplayMemberPath = "cGift";
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_comboSelection.cItem == "Gift")
    {
        string comboName = ComboBox1.Text;
        int recipId = RecipID(comboName);
        ComboBox2.ItemsSource = MainWindow.qryGiftList(recipId);
        ComboBox2.DisplayMemberPath = "cGift";
    }
}
```

I also tried instead of using `string ComboName = ComboBox1.Text;` to use `string ComboName = (string)ComboBox1.SelectedItem` but this results in a debug of:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in myMemory.exe
>    Additional Information: Unable to cast object of type 'myMemory.Name' to type 'System.string'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right event is SelectionChanged.
       `<ComboBox  x:Name="combobox1" SelectionChanged="comobox1_SelectionChanged"/>`

You can get the selected value in the event like this
         `string value = (string)combobox1.SelectedItem`;

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working, except, the second `ComboBox` shows items relating to the previous selected value. Example: apple is selected in `Combo1` and nothing shows in `Combo2`, when pineapple is selected in `Combo1`, `Combo2` then shows 'Green, Red etc' (items relating to the first selected value). I've debugged and the SelectionChanged runs using the previous selected value from the `ComboBox` not the latest value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update your code so I can see what is happening?

Comment: Try adding this to the begining of the `event e.Handled = true;`

Comment: updated the question with the code in the `SelectionChanged` event. Added `e.Handled = true;` and it still didn't work. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I guess it errors when I use `.SelectedItem` because I'm declaring it as `(string)` when my `ComboBox` is populated from class properties? When I use the class type in the brackets though it fails to compile.

Comment: Yes you can try this `var selection = ComboBox1.SelectedItem;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86837/discussion-between-nejdi-and-lturner).